# Unable to create the Write-in Product under Quote in Dynamics CRM using web-api

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-webapi

I am able to link the Existing product under quote by passing a Product ID and an UOMS ID using the post below in Postman.

```
{
"productid@odata.bind":"/products(de646511-f937-e711-8104-c4346bacc0f8)",

 "quoteid@odata.bind" : "/quotes(2f15f376-2b41-e711-8108-c4346bac2908)",

        "uomid@odata.bind": "/uoms(1cb3bab6-ed37-e711-8107-c4346baceb84)",

  "quantity":1
}
```

But my requirement is to create the Writein Product where the UOMS ID should be null which I am unable to move further without passing an UOMS ID.

It is throwing an error saying:

> need to pass UOMS ID.

Answer (score 0):

Specify that the product is a write-in product and include the required information for a write-in product in your object like this

```
{
"quantity": 1,
"quoteid@odata.bind" : "/quotes(2f15f376-2b41-e711-8108-c4346bac2908)",
"productdescription" : "My Write-in Product",
"isproductoverridden" : true,
"ispriceoverridden" : true
}
```